# Почему функция не видит глобально обьявленную структуру?

Tags: c, структуры, extern

Есть задача-не используя указатели,создатьмассив структур и присвоить значение каждой структуре в одной функции,а вывести значения введенных структур в консоль в другой функции. Я обьявил структуры как extern,но вторая функция все равно их не видит. В чем проблема?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern struct shop_info{
        char shop_name[30];
        char goods_type[30];
        char adress[30];
        char work_time[20];
        int  staff_quantity;
        int  store_number;

}arraystr[256];
 void output (size_t length)
{
    int k;
    printf("\nВы ввели данные этих магазинов:");
    for(k=0;k<length;k++)
{
    printf("\n  %s  |  %s  |  %s  |  %s  |  %i  |  %i  |",
    store[k].shop_name,store[k].goods_type,store[k].adress,store[k].work_time,store[k].staff_quantity,store[k].store_number);   
printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }



}
//========================================================================================================================
 void input()
{
    extern struct shop_info store[256];
    int i=0,k=0;
    char check[5];



    while(k!=1)
     {
     printf("\nВведите название магазина\n");
        scanf("%s",store[i].shop_name);
      printf("\nВведите тип товара\n")  ;
            scanf("%s",store[i].goods_type);
      printf("\nВведите адрес\n")  ;
                scanf("%s",store[i].adress);
      printf("\nВведите рабочее время\n")  ;
                    scanf("%s",store[i].work_time);
      printf("\nВведите количество персонала\n")  ;
                        scanf("%i",&store[i].staff_quantity);
      printf("\nВведите номер магазина\n")  ;
                            scanf("%i",&store[i].store_number);


    printf("\nХотите ввести еще один магазин? |Yes/No|\n");
    scanf("%s",check);
    if(check[0]=='n' || check[0]=='N')
    {k=1;}
i++;
}
        output(i);
}
//===================================================================
int main()
{
    input();
}
```

Comment: Объявлять `extern struct shop_info store[256];` нужно не внутри функции, а снаружи.

Comment: О каком именно "глобальном объявлении структуры" идет речь? И что в программе на С делает `#include <iostream>` и `using namespace std;`???

Answer (score 0):

Все функции прекрасно видят глобальные объявления в вашем коде. Поэтому о каком "не видит" вы ведете речь - неясно.

Однако стоит заметить, что, во-первых, объявление переменной с ключевым словом `extern` и без явно указанного инициализатора не является *определением*. У вас в программе нет определения массива `arraystr`. Хотя это и не страшно, ибо этот массив нигде в коде не используется. (Зачем вы его объявляли вообще?)

Во-вторых, объявление массива `store` внутри функции `input` тоже не является определением, по той же причине. Не понятно зачем вы вообще поместили это `extern` объявление *внутрь функции*. `extern` объявления *внутри функций* служат исключительно для ссылки на внешние определения. У вас же никакого внешнего определения массива `store` нет.

В-третьих, идентификатор `store` вообще никак не объявлен внутри функции `output`.